# Creating Dynamic Dropdown using PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, dropdown

Hello I am quite new to using PHP and HTML and I was wondering if someone could help and tell me what I'm doing wrong with my second dropdown menu? I have posted the code for my second dropdown menu. I can't figure out why my $_POST isn't working for me? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[insert_php]

  $department = $_POST['department'];

  $result2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT course FROM class WHERE department = $department;");

echo "

     <form action='process.php' method='post'>

     <select name='professor'>";

     foreach($result2 as $result2){

     {

          echo "<option selected value='$result2->course'>$result2->course</option>";


        }

     }

echo" </select>

<input type='submit' value= 'Select' />

</form>";


[/insert_php]
```

Comment: what is [insert_php][/insert_php]? @zjposz

Comment: It is just a plugin to replace the <php ?> in wordpress @ParthMahida

Comment: I try printing out my $department = $_POST['department']; and it doesn't seem like it has anything in it.

Comment: Is 'department' a number or a string?

Comment: try print_r($_POST), and see the post array have department as a key @zjposz

Comment: Department is a string @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez

Comment: Also I've tried doing that @ParthMahida and nothing appears. Here is my code for my first dropdown.

Comment: `$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT department FROM class GROUP BY department;");

 echo "

      <form action='process.php' method='post' name='dep'>

      <select name='department'>";
  
      foreach($result as $result){

      {
           echo "<option selected value='$result->department'>$result->department</option>";
         }

      }

 echo" </select>

 <input type='submit' value= 'Select' />

 </form>";`

Comment: If 'department' is a string you have to write `WHERE department='$department'` (do you see the single quotes before and after $department?).

Comment: I have tried that previously @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez. I believe the problem is my $_POST isn't working properly

Comment: In that case we need to see the code that calls this code.

Comment: I will be away from a computer for the next 2 hours but will return. Thank you for any help

Comment: there isnt anything in your post array, you have to check from which page you are coming @zjposz

Comment: Also try `echo "<option selected value='{$result2->course}'>{$result2->course}</option>";` (with curly braces before and after the variables).

Comment: The code I put in my comment is right above the code I put in the main question. That is all that is on the page. Like I said I'm very new to this so I could be missing something easily.